# Does sinning in front of another jew constitute chillul hashem?

Tags: chilul-kidush-hashem

The Kesef Mishna (Teshuva 2.5) writes that confessing a private sin publicly is a chillul hashem if someone is there who wasn’t previously aware of the sin:

בעבירות מפורסמות שבין אדם למקום, מותר לו להתוודות ברבים אבל אין מצווה, שאולי יהיה שם אדם שלא ידע בדבר ועכשיו ידע, ואיכא חילול השם.”

(Link to more info on this: https://www.dafdigest.org/yoma/Yoma%20086.pdf)

If it’s chillul hashem to revel a previous sin, is it also chillul hashem to have done the sin in front of that person?

Comment: It does not depend on the doer it mostly depends on the observer's reaction. Hilul Hashem is always (IMHO) "in someone's eyes". So if that person perceives it as "minimizing G-d's honor" or "rebelling against Heaven", it might be H"H. But if that person knows that one sins "unwillingly/unknowingly" or "regretfully" it isn't H"H.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is chilul Hashem.

Rambam Yesode Hatora 5.13:

> כל העובר מדעתו בלא אונס על אחת מכל מצוות האמורות בתורה, בשאט בנפש להכעיס--הרי זה מחלל את השם; ולפיכך נאמר בשבועת שקר, "וחיללת את שם אלוהיך, אני ה'" (ויקרא יט,יב).  ואם עבר בעשרה מישראל, הרי זה חילל את השם ברבים.  וכן כל הפורש מעבירה או עשה מצוה, לא מפני דבר בעולם, לא פחד ולא יראה, ולא לבקש כבוד, אלא מפני הבורא ברוך הוא, כמניעת יוסף הצדיק עצמו מאשת רבו--הרי זה מקדש את השם..‏
>
> 1. Whoever consciously transgresses one of the mitzvot related in the
>      Torah, without being forced to, in a spirit of derision, to arouse
>      [Divine] anger, **desecrates [God's] name**. Therefore, [Leviticus 19:12]
>      states, regarding [taking] an oath in vain: "[for] you are desecrating
>      the name of your Lord; I am God."
> 2. If he transgresses amidst ten Jews,
>      he **desecrates [God's] name in public**.

See Sefer Hamitsvot lavin 63

> והחלק השני הכולל גם כן כשיעשה האדם עבירה, אין תאווה בה ולא הנאה, אבל
>   כיוון בפעולתו המרד ופריקת עול מלכות שמים. הנה זה מחלל גם כן ולוקה.
>   ולפיכך אמר "וחללת את שם אלהיך" (ויקרא יט, יב) כי זה מכוון להכעיס בזה
>   העניין ואין הנאה גשמית בזה.‏

Comment: that’s before a minyan, here in the question it seems even one

Comment: Even here there is two cases, see the two bold

Comment: The first case is talking about if he sinned specifically to make HaShem mad.

Comment: @lo ani yes this is parallel, from the mentality point of view to the case of someone who says purposelessly that he made a sin. So there is a parallelism.  להכעיס is to explain that this is not לתיאבון. I don't understand what is to make hashem mad.

Comment: What if the man in the question does the aveira in front of less than 10 Jews and not להכעיס?

Comment: I think that the sefer hamitsvot writes עוד כ' בסהמ"צ הנז' והחלק השני הכולל ג"כ כשיעשה אדם עבירה אין תאוה בה ולא הנאה, אבל כיון בפעולתו המרד ופריקת עול מלכות שמים הנה זה מחלל ג"כ ולוקה quoted from merkevet hamishne alfandari in hebrewbooks rambam